# FastAPI - module 'app.routers.test' has no attribute 'routes'

Tags: python, fastapi

I am trying to setup an app using FastAPI but keep getting this error which I can't make sense of. My `main.py` file is as follows:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from app.routers import test

app = FastAPI()
app.include_router(test, prefix="/api/v1/test")
```

And in my `routers/test.py` file I have:

```
from fastapi import APIRouter, File, UploadFile
import app.schemas.myschema as my_schema

router = APIRouter()
Response = my_schema.Response


@router.get("/", response_model=Response)
def process(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    # Do work
```

But I keep getting the following error:

> File
> "/Users/Desktop/test-service/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py",
> line 566, in include_router
> for route in router.routes: AttributeError: module 'app.routers.test' has no attribute 'routes'
> python-BaseException

I cant make sense of this as I can see something similar being done in the sample app [here](https://github.com/tiangolo/full-stack-fastapi-postgresql/blob/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.project_slug%7D%7D/backend/app/app/api/api_v1/endpoints/items.py).

Comment: Does `app.routers.test` have a `routes` attribute?  What is `app.routers.test`?  Is it a router? I don't have this stuff on my machine, so I can't take a look, but my guess is that `app.include_router` expects a different first argument than whatever `test` is.  (this is the downside to dynamically typed languages)

Comment: it doesnt have a routes attribute but the example also doesnt have one. yes it is a router. the contents of test.py is given in question itself

Comment: I still don't see where you define what the `test` is that's being passed to `app.include_router`.  If it's `test.py`, then it's a module, not a normal Python object.  So if that's true, do you maybe want `app.include_router(test.router, prefix="/api/v1/test")`?  UPDATE: Ah, I missed this before.  The error message is telling you that `app.routers.test` is a Python Module.  I doubt that's what you want to pass into anything.  Now I'm thinking more than ever that you want to pass in `test.router` rather than `test`.

Comment: totally true. my bad

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you want:

```
app.include_router(test.router, prefix="/api/v1/test")
```

rather than:

```
app.include_router(test, prefix="/api/v1/test")
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not directly access it from the `app`, because when you add an instance of APIRouter with `include_router`, FastAPI adds every router to the `app.routes`.

```
   for route in router.routes:
        if isinstance(route, APIRoute):
            self.add_api_route(
                ...
            )
```

It does not add the route to the application instead it adds the routes, but since your router is an instance of APIRouter, you can reach the routes from that.

```py
class APIRouter(routing.Router):
    def __init__(
        self,
        routes: Optional[List[routing.BaseRoute]] = None,
        ...
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your import statement, your import should be like

```
from parentfolder.file import attribute
```

Confused? no worries let me make it simple
Any variable you use to define and assign to APIRouter, becomes your attribute.
in your example in test.py, you defined routes as your attribute `routes = APIRouter()`
that means that if you want to use it in any other place, you need to do as below

```
from routers.test import routes
```

GoodLuck